# How to best store data of dynamically created widgets in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, lambda

I'm building a Qt application with VC++ and I need several long forms with various widgets. I'm trying to allocate these widgets dynamically to make the process of adding new pages much simpler.

To do this, I'm passing a QStringList 'key' and QVector<QString> 'vec' into the QDialog that holds the form. The first character of key[i] holds the widget type and the rest holds the label. Each vec[i], on the other hand, needs to hold any corresponding information altered by the user (from the dynamically created widgets).

So far, I've tried the following inside of a for loop (each loop goes through one key):

```
char typeVal = key[i].toStdString()[0]; // widget type
key[i] = key[i].mid(1); // widget label

switch (typeVal)
{
    case 'e': // edit (lineedit)
    {
        QLineEdit *newEdit = new QLineEdit(page);
        connect(newEdit, &QLineEdit::textChanged, [&] {
            vec[vecIndex] = newEdit->text().toStdString(); });
        layout->addRow(key[i], newEdit);
        break;
    }
    // ...
}
```

However, this gives me an 'access violation reading location' due to the newEdit->text(). This might be a problem with how I'm using the lambda function slot, as I don't know much about lambda declarations. If there's a fix for this, or if the whole process is needlessly convoluted and there's a better method of tracking the widget data, I'd love to hear it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The access violation problem you report probably has the following reason.

You connect your signal to the following lambda function:

`[&] { vec[vecIndex] = newEdit->text().toStdString(); }`

where the `[&]` part tells the compiler to capture all variables *by reference*, that is, a reference gets bound to `newEdit` variable which is available then within the lambda function body. This is, however, not what you want in this situation. The reference to `newEdit` is, in fact, bound to a variable which gets destroyed almost immediately after this binding (that is, in the end of your `case` statement scope) so trying to read this variable later (at the slot invocation time) results in trying to read something from the destroyed variable, so the corresponding memory location may contain just any random value or even be unavailable for reading at all. Dereferencing the result of such reading operation results in the segmentation violation that you report.

What you want here is a *value* of `newEdit` pointer (it is a *pointer* to `QLineEdit`, not the object itself) which should be saved for later usage by your lambda function slot. I would assume that the same applies to `vecIndex` since it looks like some loop variable you described in your question so it changes its value and may be destroyed after your loop is done, but that depends on the actual context of your application. On the contrary, `vec` variable probably needs a capture by reference since you want to modify the "global" vector rather than its local copy made for the lambda function.

Assuming that, we come to the following declaration of the lambda function:

`[&vec, vecIndex, newEdit] { vec[vecIndex] = newEdit->text().toStdString(); }`

which expresses the fact that `vec` should be captured by reference while `vecIndex` and `newEdit` variables need to be captured by their values.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I knew that the '&' passed all the values by reference and '=' passed them by value, but didn't know I could pass just the vector by reference. This solution seems to work. Thanks for the reply.